# How to re-authorize a GIT commit?

Tags: git, github, git-commit

This may be a dumb question, wondering if this was possible or not? 
I have one local commit which I cherry-picked from some other branch and want to re-authorize that commit. Currently it shows Authored by 'someone else'. I want it to be re-author so that it shows Authored by 'me'. 
Is re-authorization possible?

Comment: I've created a new word: "plagiarism".

Comment: @SteeveDroz :D yes you are right..  but the case here is that I am trying to re-authorize my work..which was done some other entitlement, so has  different author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `amend` you can do reset author name.

```
$ git commit --amend --author "new-author-name <new-author@mail.com>"
```

Comment: `--reset-author` is shorter to type if you simply want to change the author to yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I think your only option here would be to amend the commit you cherry picked, and then change the author.  Something like this:

```
git checkout yourBranch
git cherry-pick <some SHA-1>
git commit --amend --author="MMK <mmk@domain.com>"
```

Since a cherry-pick is already a rewrite (read: new commit) of the original commit, you are only rewriting it once more.

But as @SteeveDroz mentioned, you should make sure than you are not intending to take credit for the work of others.